# Rotate GIF Image And Save GIF Animation

Tags: python, linux, image, gif

I have problem. :) 
I need rotate this gif [image](http://thepiratebay.su/gifs/387774dfd745716b378fdc386a572a5a.gif).

I found many many scripts, but when I rotate this image, the GIF animation stops.

How can I rotate a GIF image and keep the animation? 
Thank you.

Comment: You need to unpack the gif, rotate each frame and repack it into an animation.  I don't know of a tool that will do that in one step.

Comment: hmmm. ImageMagick :) how I can ?

Comment: `convert` in ImageMagick / GraphicsMagick can do it in one step. But I didn't mention it earlier because it's not a Python script. :) And the ancient (but still wonderful) GIF manipulation program [gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/man.html) can do it, too.

Comment: I installed ImageMagick and use for take gif from video, but where rotate gif animation don't save :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm **not** going to spell it out for you. Search for `-rotate` in the `convert` man page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use ImageMagick like this:

```
convert input.gif -rotate 90 out.gif
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the [awesome ScreenToGif tool](https://github.com/NickeManarin/ScreenToGif) https://github.com/NickeManarin/ScreenToGif/wiki/Help
2. Open the GIF file: Ctrl + O
3. In the Image tab, select all GIF frames (Ctrl + A)
4. On the Image tab toolbar, click on Flip/Rotate
5. On the right side Flip/Rotate options panel, select the appropriate option, e.g.: "Rotate Right 90"
6. On the same panel click on "Apply"
7. Go to the File tab and click on "Save As"
8. Select the file format and name and click OK.
9. Wait
10. Done